# How to merge two pandas time series objects with different date time indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two disjoint time series objects, for example

-ts1

```
 Date           Price
 2010-01-01     1800.0
 2010-01-04     1500.0
 2010-01-08     1600.0
 2010-01-09     1400.0
 Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

-ts2

```
 Date           Price
 2010-01-02     2000.0
 2010-01-03     2200.0
 2010-01-05     2010.0
 2010-01-07     2100.0
 2010-01-10     2110.0
```

How I could merge the two into a single time series that should be sorted on date? like

-ts3

```
 Date           Price
 2010-01-01     1800.0
 2010-01-02     2000.0
 2010-01-03     2200.0
 2010-01-04     1500.0
 2010-01-05     2010.0
 2010-01-07     2100.0
 2010-01-08     1600.0
 2010-01-09     1400.0
 2010-01-10     2110.0
```

Comment: @jezrael, I am sorry for the confusion between the time series and data frame. I actually meant the time series as indicated in the original post, but accidentally indicated them as df's. I am not able to apply the df.append since the  times series do not have the append method.

Comment: If you have two columns as you show, then they must be DataFrame's and therefore have the `append` method.  If they are Series objects then it must be that the `Date` is the index and `Price` are the values.  However, if that is the case, then when you print them, they will **not** print as you've shown them.  Why then won't you simply post to your question what is actually printed to avoid further confusion.  And also post what their types are via `type(ts1)`

Comment: @prabhakar - so why dont use `concat` ? `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()` should working nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for join together and then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `Date`, last for default indices [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternative:

```
df3 = df1.append(df2).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df3)
         Date   Price
0  2010-01-01  1800.0
1  2010-01-02  2000.0
2  2010-01-03  2200.0
3  2010-01-04  1500.0
4  2010-01-05  2010.0
5  2010-01-07  2100.0
6  2010-01-08  1600.0
7  2010-01-09  1400.0
8  2010-01-10  2110.0
```

EDIT:

If TimeSeries then solution is simplify:

```
s3= pd.concat([s1, s2]).sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. Without sort_index(), the series are appended separately one after the other. With sort_index(), it sorts, but I have a problem with day and month interchanged and it messes up the index and values. I have yyyy-dd-mm format in my date time index and upon sort it comes out as yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: You need `s1.index = pd.to_datetime(s1.index, format='%Y-%d-%m' )` and  `s2.index = pd.to_datetime(s2.index, format='%Y-%d-%m' )` before.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day. My csv file has date in the dd-mm-yyyy format. I actually made a mistake in the read_csv function to read the data from csv file. I should use the dayfirst=True in the read_csv, so that the date is interpreted fine. The sort_index() works perfect now.

Comment: great! Took me way to long to find such a solution. so easy it turns out

Answer (score 4):

You can set the index of each to `'Date'` and use `combine_first`

```
ts1.set_index('Date').combine_first(ts2.set_index('Date')).reset_index()

        Date   Price
0 2010-01-01  1800.0
1 2010-01-02  2000.0
2 2010-01-03  2200.0
3 2010-01-04  1500.0
4 2010-01-05  2010.0
5 2010-01-07  2100.0
6 2010-01-08  1600.0
7 2010-01-09  1400.0
8 2010-01-10  2110.0
```

If these were Series in the first place, then you could simply

```
ts1.combine_first(ts2)
```

Comment: thank you for the response. With first suggestion, I get >AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index' and with the second, I get > pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @prabhakar correct, that's because there is confusion on your part as to what your objects are.  So, that is why I offered an alternative if in fact you have Series.  You are supposed to see that and try it.  If it works, then you have a solution.