# Combine series by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The following 2 series of stocks in a single excel file:

[image]

Can be combined using the date as index?

The result should be like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems something similar here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584917/how-to-merge-two-pandas-time-series-objects-with-different-date-time-indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple `df.merge()` here:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

OR

```
df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

Comment: I will try and asnwer soon.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the dataframe is from an excel file, but your asnwer is ok

Comment: can you check the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215349/index-excel-file-by-date-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I am trying this:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
df3 = df1.append(df2).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
```