# Index Excel File by date in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing

The excel file is as following example with 3 stocks:

[image]

I would like to combine using date as index. The final result should be like:

[image]

Comment: You need to first create a df by reading excel. Use [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for that. Then create separate data frames from `df`. Each having column `date` and `Stock`. Then do `pd.merge` as in your answer.

Comment: @MayankPorwal here as we have only 3 stock symbols it will be ok as you suggested. The point is that the database has hundreds of such symbols and I would like to explore pandas to do the heavy-lifting.

Comment: @MayankPorwal The point is to combine the dates, then I can delete every second column (dates columns) by  df_01[df_01.columns[::2]]

Answer (score 0):

In the following SO I made the indexing using separated dataframes directly

[Combine series by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212463/combine-series-by-date)

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

It worked fine. This time it should be reading from an excel file.